# Running a task in background Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-activity, background, multipartform-data

Warm greetings.

I am quite new to android currently & had fallen under a fix. The concern is i am running the app which performs multipart upload to a remote uri using HttpPost, if the upload fails, the data is then saved to sqllite.

Now as soon as the application starts my app firstly queries the db & if there is any unsent data it first send it then proceed ahead.

What i am looking for is a feature via which i can run this task in background, i can not place this peice of code in onPause because i have few other intents which give a call to Camera, image viewer, gps etc... Any suggestions how can i manage this & how can i acheive this. Is there any samples/links available for implementation like this.?

PS:- I have the application with one single Activity defined in Manifest, other are the inbuilt Broadcasters like Camera Intent, Media Player etc. Just an additional info

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a Service: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link for executing the task in bg.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html